# Footer width not behaving as expected

Tags: html, css

I'm just messing around with a bit of responsive web design practice but I can't understand what I'm dong wrong down in my footer/ So I have a flexbox #footer with width set to 100vw and a second div container with width: 900px, yet this width isnt what is being displayed in the web browser? Probably something really basic, but it's been baffling me for too long now! Full pen below:

https://codepen.io/rickwall/pen/WNNmERN

```css
#footer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #3b505b;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer-container {
  max-width: 900px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: ;
}
```

```html
<section id="footer">
  <div class="footer-container">
    <div class="footer-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Brands</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Availability</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="https://github.com/" id="profile-link" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="form-container">
      <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="Name" value="Name" required>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Oh, and can anyone see what I've done wrong in my navbar for this piece of code not to display dropdown on hover?

.vanish:hover .list-menu-2 {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 40px 15px 5px 5px;
  left: 165px;
  top: -7px;
  background-color: #c3d7e0;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have ... a second div container with width: 900px

Actually, it has `max-width: 900px`, which is very different. This will only enforce a width of 900 if the natural width *exceeds* 900.

Because children of a `display: flex` element will only be as wide as they need to be to fit their contents, it will never grow to exceed 900 unless you tell it to (or if you fill it with enough content).

To do so, apply `flex: 1` (or `width: 100%`) in addition to your `max-width`.

```css
#footer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #3b505b;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer-container {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 900px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<section id="footer">
  <div class="footer-container">
    <div class="footer-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Brands</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Availability</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="https://github.com/" id="profile-link" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="form-container">
      <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="Name" value="Name" required>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

This works because `flex: 1` refers to the proportion of remaining space that this item should occupy. For example, if you had two children each with `flex: 1`, they would both grow to split the remaining space. If you had two children, one with `flex: 2`, and one with `flex: 1`, they would take up two-thirds and one-third of the remaining space, respectively.